# Arbitrary precision number is clipped

Tags: j

J clips the big integer number in the terminal (note the ellipsis in the output).

How can this be prevented?

#### Code

`!333x`

#### Output

---

1033446543458805915609396553829751655062226004168206282343290246978318859791427656855270019484987792989437595025257047708041835273259765874566592560470466922713372647724385431783663513069412389371163853300198049622987566547659856882180617030376554048981440...

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Files](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm) foreign to output to stdout like so:

```
(":!333x) (1!:2) 4
```

Or you can use the [Output Control](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm) foreign to show a longer line:

```
(9!:37) 0 698 0 222

!333x
10334465434588059156093965538297516550622260041682062823432902469783188597914276568552700194849877929894375950252570477080418352732597658745665925604704669227133726477243854317836635130694123893711638533001980496229875665476598568821806170303765540489814402234159901540440432134155844542962445153646330595588291605924429211352279943471372817279938720974895260387784578239150931816946786416232516666251965421919651838044618050991294403546958930745419743836966520198735201123255884089263272829846640538826979843642885775791641575109178753509580001660392092396798648924375401024147883702298145910046889402880394195369984000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: You can "extract" any portion of `!333x` by, for example `(a+i.b) { ":!333x`

Comment: Good enough. Your solution runs in the Windows Console, but not in the GTK terminal. Anyway, I understand that in practice there's no need to display such a huge number if it's stored and used correctly. Thanks.

Comment: For the terminal, maybe it's better to use `9!:37`. See the second (edited) part of the answer. Forgot to mention that. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can also just write like this:

```
stdout":!333x
```