# how to show the entire results or show more results

Tags: j

I want to be able to show more calculation results, or even the entire results on the console in `J`. For example, the following only shows

```
   i.1000
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88...
```

up to 88.

How do I show the first `200` results, or even the entire 1000 results? The only way I know of now is to write it to a file and read it outside of console.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack Overflow, please read this (http://sscce.org/) and make those adjustments to your question in order to earn a response.

Comment: This is a valid question about [tag:J], which is a programming language. Please do not close.

Comment: Relevant: [Arbitrary precision number is clipped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11695330/349708)

Comment: I second the opinion that this is a valid question and it is worded well enough to be understood by people familiar with J console's quirks. Please unclose.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

**Non-programmatically:**

In the console, Edit > Configure...

Below "Category", select "Parameters". In the "Session Manager" group box, set "Max Line Length to your required size. Click OK. This will save it to your personnal preferences.

**Programmatically:**

Use foreign [`9!:37`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm#36) :

```
Output Control. A 4-element vector that controls session manager output:

end-of-line sequence    0 line feed; 2 carriage return line feed
maximum line length Output lines are truncated at this length and “...” appended.
maximum line before     If the total number of output lines exceeds the sum of “maximum lines before” b and “maximum lines after” a , then the first b lines are output, followed by a line of “...”, followed by the last a lines.
maximum line after  See above.

The defaults for output controls are 0 256 0 222 .
```

So, for example:

```
9!:37 [ 0 1000 0 222
```

That will only set it as wide as the value you give it. To size it to the value you want, you're going to have to determine what size you need to output, so say :

```
outputsizes =. 9!:36'' NB. Get values
valuetodisplay =. i. 1000
printsize =. # ": valuetodisplay
9!:37 [ printsize 1 } outputsizes
```

Answer (score 2):

The length of the displayed line is determined by the foreign conjunction 9!:37

First, store the default so you can easily go back

```
   t=. 9!:36 '' NB. The current default
0 256 0 222
```

First number - End of line indicator 0 for LF and 2 for CRLF
Second number - Maximum line length (this is what you want to change)
Third number - Maximum number of lines before ... (b)
Fourth number - Maximum number of lines after ... (a)

If a + b is more than the number of lines to be shown, 
then the first b lines are shown followed by ... then the last a lines.

```
   9!:37 [ 0 700 0 222   NB. the [ is to separate the integer list from the conjunction
   i.1000
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 20...

9!:37 t NB. Reset back to stored default

   i. 1000
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88...
```

This works with the J front end, but I have not yet tested with console. Since your defaults look the same with console and there is no indication that I can find in the dictionary that console works differently than the front end, I would expect this to work. Let me know if there is a difference in your console.

Cheers, bob